# How to send back MS word cursor focus on current document after click in Task Pane

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I have developed a Word Add-in using word java script API. When i click in Task pane to do some action the cursor focus removes from current document, i am not able to edit the document until click back on the document. 
Please advice me how i can set back cursor focus back to current document when doing some actions in Task Pane.

Thanks.

Comment: Just for the record: As @JuanBalmori stated it's currently not possible for Office Add-ins. For legacy COM or VSTO add-ins you can use a workaround involving sending an F10 keystroke twice to the main window. This will put the focus back to the main document: `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{F10}");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{F10}");`

Comment: In now times is it possible or not or any event for get focus on document after click on taskpane?.

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible to do today. The user needs to click back in the document so it gets the focus.

Comment: On windows desktop the user may of course use alt+w instead of clicking

Comment: Has there been any progress on this?

Comment: There is still no API to achieve this. other than the user clicking on it or navigating back to the document as suggested in the comment above from Arne.

Comment: Currently, Is it possible to set focus from the task pane to MS word document on a button click in the task pane?